# Using Range.End

Tags: vba, excel

As you can see from the sample below the following piece of code

```
mr = Range("L" & i - 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(i, 12).Formula = "=SUM(L" & (i - 1) & ":L" & mr & ")"
```

works fine most of the time except when there is a single line to be summed up things are going wrong.

sample: the second sum is 177 (48 + 129 above) instead of 48 while the rest is fine. the lines have been added here for formatting purposes, the sheet contains numbers only.

```
...
02/07/2014    50      4
-----------------------
02/07/2014          129   =SUM(...)

06/07/2014    50     48
-----------------------
02/07/2014          177   =SUM(...)

09/07/2014    60      8
09/07/2014     8     26
09/07/2014     8     26
09/07/2014    11     48
09/07/2014  1800      1
-----------------------
09/07/2014          109   =SUM(...)

16/07/2014    60      8
16/07/2014     8     26
16/07/2014    11     48
16/07/2014  1800      1
-----------------------
16/07/2014           83   =SUM(...)
```

I know the problem could be circumvented programmatically e.g. using a loop. The question is, what am I doing wrong with `Range.End` usage?

Comment: What is your full code, for example, variable `i`?

Comment: You start `i` from the bottom? This is the default behaviour when you Ctrl-UP/DOWN on cells with empty cells in between. It cannot tell if the data is beginning/end of a series. You may want to add a special case to check the difference between `mr` and `i`.

Comment: @PatricK: I guess you meant `If Abs(mr-i)=*3* Then mr=i-1`. Nice thought, but this will lead to false positives: `mr-i` can legitimately be `3` if there are three items to sum.

Comment: to refine my question, put `MsgBox (ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Row)` into a macro and try it.

Comment: @PatricK: I understand what you are saying, still the behaviour looks weird to me. when there are two or more nonempty cells it does stop correctly, below the first empty cell. but when the cell above is empty it goes to the first nonempty cell or to the top. I do not feel it is consistent.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, may be check for empty cells above and below for 1 unit series for each `mr` stop. @jemenfou, can you let us know how you start the `i`?

Comment: @jemenfou: That's the documented behaviour of the `.End` method. It reproduces the behaviour of the End key when manually navigating a worksheet. If you want to use it, then that's what you have to work with.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: `CTRL+ARROW KEY moves to the edge of the current data region in a worksheet.`. You may be right but I found nothing about moving to the next data region.

Comment: @jemenfou: Granted, it is (surprise!) poorly documented. But the behaviour is fairly obvious if you try it out when navigating a worksheet manually.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @PatricK's comment but fixing the false positives:

```
If mr - i = 3 And IsEmpty(Range("L" & i - 2)) Then mr = i - 1
```